# How to know whether a request param is missing and throw exception using Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

When I get a request from client in my controller I do:

```
def index
  if (params[:event] == nil || params[:year] == nil || params[:country] == nil)
    raise some_error
  end
end
```

Is there a better way to perform it in rails 3.2?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This does the same thing, and though it's a bit more verbose, it's DRYer because it alleviates the need to directly specify each param key in the conditional:

```
params_hash = []
keys = [:event, :year, :country]

params.each do |key, value|
    if keys.include?(key)
        params_hash << value
    end
end

if params_hash.include?(nil)
    raise some_error
end
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
keys = [:event, :year, :country]
unless (keys - (params.keys & keys)).blank?
  raise some_error
end
```